# rsyncを使ってフォルダーをコピーした結果のフォルダーサイズの違いについて

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

rsyncを使ってフォルダー全体を別サーバーにコピーした時、サイズの違いが生じており困っています。もしどなたか解決方法がわかりましたら、ご教授をお願いしたく、ここで質問させていただいています。

少し状況を説明させていただきます。

現在2台のサーバー（A,Bとしておきます）を使用しています。
どちらのOSもubuntu 16.04に設定してあります。

サーバーAにあるフォルダーをサーバーBにコピーしたいです。
そのフォルダーは以下のように複数のファイルを含んでいます。

```
Nov132018
├── test.AQ863.1.1.h264
├── test.AQ863.1.2.h264
├── test.AQ863.1.3.h264
├── test.AQ863.1.4.h264
└── test.AQ863.1.5.h264
```

以下のコマンドを使用して、このフォルダー全体を、サーバーBにコピーしました。

```
rsync -av -e ssh /media/user1/1C3C-F8AC/Nov132018 amori@ipaddress:/tank/user1/tmpNAS/NAS1/movies
```

サーバーB側で転送されたフォルダーを確認したところ、すべてのフォルダーを含めてすべてのファイルは転送されていました。

しかし、問題はフォルダーのサイズが20倍になっていました。

具体的には、
サーバーA側では

```
$ ls -lh Nov132018/
total 504M
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 504M Nov 13 04:16 test.AQ863.1.1.h264
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1    0 Nov 13 04:26 test.AQ863.1.2.h264
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1    0 Nov 13 04:36 test.AQ863.1.3.h264
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1    0 Nov 13 04:46 test.AQ863.1.4.h264
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1    0 Nov 13 04:56 test.AQ863.1.5.h264
```

でしたが、

サーバーB側では

```
$ ls -lh Nov132018/
total 10G
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amori amori 504M Nov 13 04:16 test.AQ863.1.1.h264
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amori amori    0 Nov 13 04:26 test.AQ863.1.2.h264
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amori amori    0 Nov 13 04:36 test.AQ863.1.3.h264
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amori amori    0 Nov 13 04:46 test.AQ863.1.4.h264
-rwxr-xr-x 1 amori amori    0 Nov 13 04:56 test.AQ863.1.5.h264
```

でした。

転送されたファイルのサイズは正しいにも関わらず、フォルダーのサイズが500Mと10Gと大きく違っています。

なぜこの様な問題が生じているのか、分かりません。
サーバーB側でも500Mに抑えたいです。
そのような方法をお知りの方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

---

原因が分かってきましたので、すこし追加情報を記入しておきます。

どうやら原因はblock sizeのようです。
dfコマンドを使ってしらべましたら、
サーバーAのblock size(1K-blocks)は60049056
サーバーBのblock size(1K-blocks)は10978791680
でした。

サーバーBには他のデータもありますので、block sizeを変更するとどうなるか分かりませんので、ここでストップしています。もし助言があれば、お知らせしていただけると幸いです。

Comment: totalで表示されるのはファイルサイズの合計ではなくて、ブロック数の合計 なので 10Gは 10GB という意味ではありません。ファイルサイズの合計は `df -hs Nov132018/` で確認出来ると思うので、A,B両者を比較すると どうなるか試してみてもらえますか？

Answer (score 1):

sparse ファイルをコピーしたせいではないかと。`rsync` に `--sparse` オプションを付与してコピーしなおしてみてください。

やり直す前にコピー先のファイルは一旦削除してください。`rsync` は同期(コピーしなおし)の判定に sparse 状態の差は見ないので。

Answer (score 0):

サーバAでハードリンクされていたものがサーバBで別のファイルになっているような気がします。
もしそうであればrsyncに「-H」オプションを追加でつけると良さそうな気がします。

```
rsync -avH -e ssh (省略)
```

Comment: ご指摘、ありがとうございます。自分でも調べてーH(ハードリンク)も行っておりましたが、結果に変化がありませんでした。なにか根本が違っているのでしょうかね？